# Dozer mapping for Hibernate object to DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, dto, dozer

I try to use Dozer to convert my domain entity to DTO objects.
So, I want to convert PersistentList, PersistentBag, ... from my domain entity to ArrayList, ... in my DTO objects to avoid lazy problem.

This is an example of two of my domain entity :

```
public class User {
      private Collection<Role> roles;
      ...
}

public class Role {
      private Collection<User> users;
      ...
}
```

My DTO objects are the same except that class are of types DTO. So, to convert domain to DTO objects, I use the following Dozer mapping :

```
 <configuration>
  <custom-converters>
   <converter type=com.app.mapper.converter.BagConverter">
    <class-a>org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag</class-a>
    <class-b>java.util.List</class-b>
   </converter>
  </custom-converters>
 </configuration>

 <mapping>
  <class-a>com.app.domain.User</class-a>
  <class-b>com.app.dto.UserDTO</class-b>
 </mapping>

 <mapping>
  <class-a>com.app.domain.Role</class-a>
  <class-b>com.app.dto.RoleDTO</class-b>
 </mapping>
```

BagConverter is a Dozer custom converter and that is its code :

```
  public class BagConverter<T> extends DozerConverter<PersistentBag, List>{

 public BagConverter() {
  super(PersistentBag.class, List.class);
 }

 public PersistentBag convertFrom(List source, PersistentBag destination) {
  PersistentBag listDest = null;

  if (source != null) {

   if (destination == null) {
    listDest = new PersistentBag();
   } else {
    listDest = destination;
   }

   listDest.addAll(source);
  }

  return listDest;
 }

 public List convertTo(PersistentBag source, List destination) {
  List listDest = null;

  if (source != null) {

   if (destination == null) {
    listDest = new ArrayList<T>();
   } else {
    listDest = destination;
   }

   if (source.wasInitialized()) {
    listDest.addAll(source);
   }
  }

  return listDest;
 }}
```

So, I get a User object that contains a PersistentBag with roles. I apply dozer mapper map on that object to obtain UserDTO object. The result that I obtain is a UserDTO object with a ArrayList of Role and no an ArrayList of RoleDTO like I wished.

I thought that even if I used custom converter, dozer will convert the content of my list. It's not the right way ? If no, how to do to convert my domain entity to dto object by replacing persitent collections to classic java collections ?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain.

Comment: Retagged: 'java' instead of 'domain'. I hope you don't mind, but I believe it might help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Unfortunately when you register a `CustomConverter` you take the whole responsibility for mapping an object (collection in your case) including all its contents, properties, elements, etc.</strike>

As I see now (I didn't see it before, it has to be some kind of new feature). There's a possibility to use `MapperAware` interface as described at the end of [chapter for Custom Type Converters in Dozer docs](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html). I guess this is exactly what would suite your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to use Dozer to convert my domain entity to DTO objects. So, I want to convert PersistentList, PersistentBag, ... from my domain entity to ArrayList, ... in my DTO objects to avoid lazy problem.

I get the last sentence but I don't understand why you need to deal with [`o.h.c.PersistentBag`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentBag.html) (and so on) since this class **is** a `List`. Just use something like this:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>com.myapp.domain.User</class-a>
  <class-b>com.myapp.dto.UserDTO</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>roles</a>
    <b>roles</b>
    <a-hint>com.myapp.domain.Role</a-hint>
    <b-hint>com.myapp.dto.RoleDTO</b-hint>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

And perform the conversion before to detach entities (that's the key of your problem).

Comment: I guess the reason is that OP is using some methods not declared in `List` interface, e.g. `wasInitialized()`.

Comment: My main goal is to transfer DTO object to presentation layer that is in GWT so hibernate collections aren't suported for serialization by GWT.

So, I tought to convert hibernate collections in classic java collections to avoid that problem.

Comment: @sylsau Yes, I get that. But I don't see how dealing with `PersistentBag` does solve anything. You just need to make the conversion when Entities are still attached.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested an other solution witout custom converter like that :

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.myapp.domain.User</class-a>
    <class-b>com.myapp.dto.UserDTO</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>roles</a>
        <b>roles</b>
        <a-hint>com.myapp.domain.Role</a-hint>
        <b-hint>com.myapp.dto.RoleDTO</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

There is another problem. When Dozer try to convert roles from User to roles of RoleDTO in UserDTO, I get a lazy initialisation exception from Hibernate because roles in User is in EAGER mode.

So, I don't know how to do that mapping. I continue to search a way to solve these problems

Comment: Do the conversion before to detach entities, that's all.

Comment: Hi Pascal, what do you mean by doing the conversion before detach entities? You mean doing mapping in the transactional layer?

Answer (score 0):

As Pascal says, I don't get the point of using PersistentBags directly. If in your @Entity POJO you declare your list of roles as a classic `java.util.List` then Hibernate will automatically uses its internal representation. That is also the reason while you cannot use your POJO in the serialization process. To clarify:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  private java.util.List<Role> roles = new java.util.Arraylist<Role>(); //Hibernate doesn't really care about this new Arraylist stuff, it will use its org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList
  ... //other fields and methods
}
```

Now, when you want to convert your Entity POJO into the DTO object, you just have to use the mapping suggested by Pascal, aka

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>com.myapp.domain.User</class-a>
  <class-b>com.myapp.dto.UserDTO</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>roles</a>
    <b>roles</b>
    <a-hint>com.myapp.domain.Role</a-hint>
    <b-hint>com.myapp.dto.RoleDTO</b-hint>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

doing the conversion before you close the transaction to avoid the lazy initialization exception, eg:

```
@Transactional
public UserDTO getUser(...) {
  User user = dao.getUser(...);
  UserDTO dto = //Place your Dozer conversion here
  return dto;
}
```

As I small note, I was using Dozer for the same reason and this was working like charm.

Comment: Could this solution work if there were a mismatch in the number of roles between UserDTO and User? (e.g. a role has been revoked from the user through the web interface, so the UserDTO object has one less role than the User hibernate object)

Comment: @TaoufikMohdit, not sure I understand your question completely, but yes. Basically, when you convert from `UserDTO` to `User` you are not considering any database. Then (and this is the guess) when you update the data on the database, `Hibernate` will take care of merging your entity with the one saved and to update the database: of course, in your case you want first to convert from `UserDTO` to `User` and then you want to execute the calls to the db. On Hibernate operations: http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples

Comment: Thanks for your response! The approach you described would work with the method org.dozer.Mapper#map(Object source, Class<T> destinationClass), but this assumes all attributes are mapped in the DTO (otherwise, attributes not mapped will be nullified). If some of the attributes are excluded from the mapping, I think the other method org.dozer.Mapper#map(Object source, Object destination) [where  the destination object is the entity fetched from the database] would work. However, it does not seem to work properly with Collection attributes [roles attribute in the example above]